# How can I reduce the memory taken by ImageView with hight resolution image?

Tags: android, memory, imageview

I have following Image as src in ImageView. I use this as background image.
This makes my application memory to grow from ~5MB to ~20M.

[image]

This is the code that uses this image: (android:id="@+id/listViewBackground" is the imageview i'm talking about)

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ContentLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/ButtonsMenu"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listViewBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="center"            
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leftHeader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_green"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Title_BatteryLevel"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rightHeader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Title_Duration"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/AdLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/AdLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I need this image to much different screen sizes so its in hight resolution.
I want also that the lines will be seen.

How can I reduce the memory taken by my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,  cut your image down to just the repeatable section.

Second, follow this tutorial on how to apply a background image to a View (in this case your Relative layout "listViewBackground" ) http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-tile-background-image-in-android.html